# Go standard for file extensions in web development?

Tags: go, web, naming-conventions

I'm learning Go but I can't find this answer anywhere. Is there any official standard for file extensions in web development? I've seen multiple conventions like `.tmpl` and `.gtpl`, which is what? Thanks.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: This is completely opinion-based so not posting an answer, and Voker is right, there is absolutely no standard or even any particularly popular convention. Personally I like something like ".tpl.html" because ending in ".html" means I can open the file in a random editor or browser and it will be handled more or less correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no fixed standard, but there are some fairly common practices.  For templates on web projects, I use the extension appropriate for the type of file it is, e.g. `.html`, `.css`, etc.  That's what's done in the widely-read-and-cited [Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_10) blog post on the official Go blog, which makes it fairly standard.  I find it useful for easy syntax highlighting without changing my editor's settings/config, and processing by other tools.  I put these templates in a `/templates/` directory to keep them separate from non-template files.

I've seen and used `.tmpl` before, it's in official docs for both html and text template packages, which makes that fairly standard too, and I think it makes sense if you're making a file-type-agnostic template, or you don't have any associations that are useful by more specialized file type.

For Go code files, I always use the `.go` extension, which works well with the Go toolset.  It's what you generally see in official Go documentation, such as [this introductory document on How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization).  For executables, I don't append any file extension.  The default result when you `go build <name>.go`is an executable called `<name>`, and so that makes it a common practice.

Comment: Mmmh that's quite contradictory because [in this example](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#example_Template_helpers) they're using `.tmpl` files... I guess they're not using a fixed convention too

Comment: @Cris that's the text template documentation -- which would make it more generic -- not the html template documentation.  But you can actually find `.tmpl` in the html documentation too, so it is used in both package docs.  But then not in the blog.  I agree with the other comments that there is no fixed, universal standard.